# Building psensor or getting started building GTK stuff in general

Tags: compiling, gtk3, psensor

Background: I'm an experienced and competent firmware / driver C / C++ programmer with years in Windows work and just (last 5 years) switched exclusively to Ubuntu. Mostly I work in embedded systems, but I've done some with OS CLI, servers, drivers and a bit with GUI but only in Windows, never worked with GTK.

There is an open source package that appears to have not been updated in forever, but is still useful and apparently used by many people. This surprises me. Like... is this really the source code for psensor? Is there not some fork of it which is actually installed on Ubuntu?
https://gitlab.com/jeanfi/psensor/

And assuming this IS the correct source, I want to change this one line:
https://gitlab.com/jeanfi/psensor/-/blob/master/src/lib/pgtop2.c#L98
from

`v = ((double)mem.free) * 100.0 / mem.total;`

to

`v = ((double)mem.available) * 100.0 / mem.total;`

So I've followed the directions and cloned it, then looked at and finally run `./config.guess` ('cause there is no just ./config) and then `make` says there is nothing to do, which makes sense, because there is only an Makefile.am file, which I've never seen. The google group doesn't seem to have any up to date advice on making the thing... autoconf fails.

And I'm so far under the water here that I'm stopping. Anyone know how to actually build this thing? Or what keywords I should use to search for an introduction to building this sort of thing?